# Is it possible to reproduce the behavior of an excel table in python, so that table values are dynamic?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*please edit the title if the wording is incorrect*

Imagine to have a dataframe, with some numeric values in it. Now imagine that the columns in said dataframe are the result of calculations based on external values.

Let's make a simplified example; I have 2 tables, table_1 and table_2. Values on table_2 are the result of values in table_1 times a variable, let's call it alpha:

```sql
alpha = 0.5

table_1:                                           table_2:

     col_A   |     col_B                                col_A2    |    col_B2
-------------+---------------                      ---------------+---------------
      5      |       3                                    2.5     |      1.5
-------------+---------------                      ---------------+---------------
     12      |       6                                     6      |       3
```

In excel, if I edit the value in the first cell of table_1, the first cell in table_2 would change and no other operation would be done. In python, as far as I know, I need to rerun the piece of code that defines table_2, and everything will be recalculated from scratch, even if only a single value changed.

In general this is not a problem, but the reason I'm asking this is because I need to build an interface in which a user can play with the original data and immediately receive visual feedback on the derived one (something like those crossfilter dashboards in javascript)

If we extend this problem to thousands of rows and a more complex operation, the process slows down a lot, and it kills the purpose of having a UI in the first place.

So, what can I do in python to achieve this? Is it even possible? If not, what are my alternatives?

Any info is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: no, I don't think it's possible without re-running the underlying operation. I would look into `streamlit` I think it handles things like this. If you're using JS you could either reproduce the data in JS so its dynamic or use SQL and create a view. There are probably many other methods as well

Comment: Dang. I'm not using JS but my colleague is, so I can work with him potentially. Can you briefly explain what you mean that data in JS is dynamic?

PS: streamlit is DOPE! I didn't know such a thing existed.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea here is to keep track of what values (cells) a formula uses.

So rather than actively updating all cells in your workbook, you would do the following:

1. Cell A1 is updated by the user
2. Immediately after having been updated, the update-procedure is triggered
3. The update procedure looks at all cells whose formula depends on the value of A1, and updates those, then firing the update procedure again for all those cells.

This way, you only update the cells you actually need to update.

Comment: Maybe I explained myself wrongly, but I'm not using excel, I'm just trying to simulate its behavior

Comment: I know. That's what I am suggesting. Create a datastructure that mimics the behaviour of a 2-dimensional array (offering subscript access), and also uses this technique of update-on-demand.

Comment: Oh ok, I had missed what you were suggesting. I fear that this goes well beyond my capabilities, I'm not even sure where to start to build a new data structure, let alone make it dynamic.

Comment: That would be the easy part. You'd also need to build something to represent formulas. Potentially parsing them from a string.

Comment: Uhm, I think there is a misunderstanding, because I'm having a trouble following your logic. The calculations that connect the 2 tables are predetermined, the user would not have to edit them. The idea is to have a sort of dashboard, in which a user can put values in table_1, and immediately see how table_2 changes through charts and visualizations. Table_2, conversely, is a result of combination of rows in table one and would be hidden.

Comment: I thought the formula would also be dynamic. In any case, you would need a way to manage change propagation. Not only on the backend (where this smart table model lives) but also on the frontend (only updating the cells that need to be updated)

Comment: On the frontend I think I can handle this using plotly Dash datatable object, which was built also for this purpose. On the backend, yeah, that's where my dilemma starts. Anyway, thanks for the help, I hope I will find a solution.